# How to query records based on date

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a DataTable with 5 columns with type of int, string and DateTime. I have written a LINQ query to filter records by date. How do I get records by today and yesterday?

```
var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(datas => datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") == DateTime.Now.Date)
          .Select(datas => new { ---})
```

I am not getting records. My record is at 14/05/2013 10:00 am.  I dont need to query by time, I need to query only by date. Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

The dates of yesterday and today are the dates between midnight yesterday (including) and midnight tomorrow (excluding):

```
var upperBound = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var lowerBound = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(datas => datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") < upperBound)
                       && datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= lowerBound)
          .Select(datas => new { ---})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `==` which will only match `14/05/2013 12:22` (time of posting)

Use:

```
var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(datas => datas.Field("Date") <= DateTime.Now.Date).Select(datas => new { ---})
```

Which will get any date before `12:22` or use `&&` and specify another condition, such as:

```
var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(datas => datas.Field("Date") <= DateTime.Now.Date && datas.Field("Date") >= '2013-05-14 09:00').Select(datas => new { ---})
```

Note: You can also use `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5)` rather than the hard coded `2013-05-14`

Comment: Thanks, Got it

 ** For Today : **


var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(datas => datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).Select(datas => new {--});
                
** For Yesterday : **

 var Data = _dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(datas => datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) && datas.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Select(datas => new{--});

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
var Data = from datas in _dtAll.AsEnumerable()
      let diff = (DateTime.Now.Date - datas.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date)
      where diff.Days >= 0 && diff.Days <= 1
      select new { ---}
```